# How do I typeset a low single quotation mark?

Tags: symbols, punctuation

How do I typeset a low "9" single quotation mark such as that seen below?

[image]

Comment: The apostrophe is part of the font, like the letter a or the letter M or the comma. Do you want to know, which font that is?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your fast reply. Ah really? I thought it is not possible to make such an apostrophe. Everytime I tried I only get this one: `hello' . But I would like to have the first apostrophe at the beginning at the bottom like above on the photo. I hope you see what I mean. Thank you!!

Comment: this question isn't actually about the apostrophe.  it's about the quoting style of a particular language.  a change of title would make this more clear and useful for future seekers of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest way is to use `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote*{passen}

\enquote{Geschachtelt kann der \enquote{Asterisk} weggelassen werden.}
\end{document}
```

This package searches the active language and uses its typical style. Above an example for a German text. You can switch languages of course and you can define what ever apostrophes or guillemets later.

Just read the documentation to this great package.